# How can I create a PXE boot image that runs a single executable on startup?

Tags: linux, pxe-boot

I'm in the process of setting up a compute cluster with the intent of using it for some parallel computing experiments. I have a single executable which I'd like to run on this cluster.

Due to operational constraints on said cluster I can only deploy this executable as a PXE boot image. Unfortunately, the only "ready-made" images I've been able to find are installation ones intended to install a particular distro. They don't particularly appear easy to modify.

Can someone perhaps provide some pointers as to how I could go about creating a pxelinux image that loads the linux kernel and subsequently run an executable?

Comment: Is your executable its own operating system?!

Comment: @MichaelHampton No, it's not. It's a program I compiled and have all required shared libraries for, so it should run on any linux distro.

Comment: Well, then you can just PXE boot your favorite Linux distro.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm sorry if it's a dumb question, but how do I include my program in the files being distributed to the machines, and subsequently have the machines execute it once they have finished booting?

Comment: Instead of booting the kernel/initrd for the _installer_, you boot the kernel/initrd for an _installed system_. Your distro's documentation should explain how to install the OS for PXE booting and root filesystem on the network.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Do you have an example of such documentation for a particular distro? The only ones I've been able to find talk about the installer.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/ch-disklesssystems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ubuntu-18-x86_64-initrd.gz:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz
gzip -d initrd.gz
mkdir image
cd image
cpio -idmv < ../initrd
```

Now copy your executable, required shared libraries, and other files needed by your executable into `image/`. Edit `etc/inittab`. You probably want to remove `::sysinit:`. Change `::respawn:` to be an invocation of your executable.

```
find . -print0 | cpio --null -ov --format=newc | gzip -9 > ../initrd-bionic-foo.gz
```

Copy `initrd-bionic-foo.gz` to your tftp server. Sample pxelinux.cfg entry:

```
default foo
label foo
kernel boot/Ubuntu-18.04-x86_64-linux
append initrd=boot/initrd-bionic-foo.gz
```